# Can't init list in Realm

Tags: android, realm

Android 3.2, java 1.7. Realm 4.1.0

Here code:

```
public class LocalizedString extends RealmObject {
  private RealmList<TranslatedString> translations;

public void cascadeUpdate(Realm realm, LocalizedString that) {
        if (!EqualsUtil.areEqualContentLists(this.translations, that.translations)) {
            if (that.translations == null) {
                setTranslations(null);
            } else {
                if (translations == null) {
                    translations = realm.copyToRealm(new RealmList<TranslatedString>()); // error!!!
                }
            }
        }
    }


public class TranslatedString extends RealmObject {
    private String locale;
    private String value;
}
```

I need to init list when `translations  = null`. So I try this:

```
translations = realm.copyToRealm(new RealmList<TranslatedString>());
```

Here compile error:

```
error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that List<E> conforms to RealmList<TranslatedString>
```

Comment: Well yeah, `copyToRealm` returns `List<T>` and not a `RealmList<T>`.